# React Native connecting frontend and backend having network error while fetching API using axios

Tags: react-native

**RegisterScreen.js**

```
const [name, setName] = useState("")
const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
const navigation = useNavigation()


async function handleRegister(){
    // e.preventDefault()
    const user = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        password: password
    }
    console.log(user)

    await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/register", user).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        Alert.alert(
        "Registration successful",
        "You have been registered Successfully"
        );
        setName("");
        setEmail("");
        setPassword("");
    }).catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert(
        "Registration Error",
        "An error occurred while registering"
        );
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**api/index.js**

```
app.post('/login', async(req,res) => {
try{
    const { email, password } = req.body

    const user = await User.findOne({ email })
    if(!user){
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "User not found" })
    }

    if(user.password !== password){
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Incorrect Password" })
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id}, secretKey)

    res.status(200).json({ token })
} catch(error){
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Login Error" })
}
})
```

I am trying to fetch the API from the react native frontend side by using axios and when I try to submit the form data it shows out the network error. May I ask will there be some installations missing in order to fix the network error?

Comment: You try to access Localhost. Do you have the API Endpoint on you Mobile Phone??

Comment: How to have the api endpoint on mobile phone debugger?

Comment: i mean you are doing "axios.post("http://localhost:8000/register", user)" where you try to send a request to localhost. Since you are using React Native i assume you do it on a Mobile Phone. Or do you use Android Studio Android Emulator?

Comment: I am running on android emulator

Answer (score 1):

Well, Localhost doesnt work on an Emulator. You can check your Emulator Settings, but before, try using this IP: "10.215.90.64". Android Studio basically binds it to your Localhost.

So your updated Request looks like:

```
await axios.post("http://10.215.90.64:8000/register", user).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    Alert.alert(
    "Registration successful",
    "You have been registered Successfully"
    );
    setName("");
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
}).catch((error) => {
    Alert.alert(
    "Registration Error",
    "An error occurred while registering"
    );
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Is it a best way to run the app using mobile phone?

Comment: It doesnt matter, if you use your phone, you have to use the Adress of your PC / Server running the API

Comment: May I ask how to set up if I want to use mobile phone to run the app?